# Determining where added latency is coming from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-programming, latency, cloudflare

I have a website that I can see in Newrelic and Nginx spends a very small amount of time processing per request, even at the 99% level. Nevertheless, I see a lot of added processing time when actual users hit the site (+100-900ms). I'd trying to figure out lowest hanging fruit to work on at this point, but don't know how to go about isolating what's taking up this additional time. It's being spent somewhere between replies leaving my content boxes (in AWS), going through my DNS provider (Cloudflare), and winding up at the user's laptop. What's a good way to see where the most time is being spent?

Comment: What type of instance? Where is the instance (server) and the client? How many other apps on server? What kind of application and DB? Is DB at the same machine and utilise a lot I/O? What value of CPU, Load Average and disk system IOPS? Have you tried to run the app on same environment but different region / availability zone  / instance type?

Comment: @mikhailov like I said, processing on the box gets done fast. I can curl requests from the box to localhost and get responses between 10-50ms, which I'm completely fine with (and is besides the point). The bulk of time right now is being spent between replies leaving backend boxes in AWS, going through cloudflare, and reaching a user's laptop. Even users in the same region as the content box are experiencing >100ms lag. I've had the same issues in different regions, but haven't tried different instance types. CPU and I/O are low, so can't imagine that would help.

Comment: Have you tried to isolate it at least to bypass one thing at a time?

Comment: Yes. I hit my load balancers directly and still get nearly identical lag, so the problem is not related to cloudflare, but I'm more looking for general advice here in such a situation. In general, where might this sort of lag come from?